# How much bigger is a combination index than a single index?

Tags: sql, mysql, indexing

For MySQL speciffically, but I'm guessing the structures are similar across most brands of SQL.  Are combination indexes much bigger than single indexes?  For example, would the amount of space needed to hold INDEX(col1, col2) be the same as the amount of space to hold INDEX(col1) + INXEX(col2)?  I'm not exactly running into this in development right now, just curious.

Comment: Note that index on (col1, col2) allows you to search by col1 or by col1 and col2, but not by col2 alone.

Comment: @9000: Right, but it works faster when I'm joining on multiple columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With InnoDB, The size of the combined index would be roughly the size of `col1` plus the size of `col2` plus the size of the table's primary key (or 4 bytes if using MyISAM).

With InnoDB or MyISAM, the combined index should be smaller than two separate indexes, since with two separate indexes the primary key (or 4 byte row pointer) would be included twice (once in each index).

Comment: I know this to be true with InnoDB for non-unique keys, is it always true?

Comment: @Danosaure - Yes, I believe so (at least for InnoDB).  See the last paragraph here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html

Comment: As said, true for InnoDB, but not always true. I don't think this applies to MyISAM engine.

Comment: @Danosaure - You are right.  MyISAM uses a 4-byte record pointer in its indexes.  I'll adjust my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

No, it would be smaller than the sum of both indexes. How much smaller depends on various factors like if you have a clustered index on the table, its length and several other things. Generally speaking: The larger col1 and col2 are, the more will the sum of the indexes approach the combined index, because then they dominate the other factors.

Comment: So, the size of INDEX(col1, col2) is generally smaller than the size of INDEX(col1)+INDEX(col2), but at the amount of rows increases, the combination index will become closer to the size of having separate indexes?

Comment: So, the size of INDEX(col1, col2) is generally smaller than the size of INDEX(col1)+INDEX(col2), but at the amount of rows increases, the combination index will become closer to the size of having separate indexes?

Comment: @PMV: No, the amount of rows does little to nothing to the relative size difference. It's the size of the column content. The larger the columns the less is the relative difference.